# check if a name in one dataframe exist in other dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, group-by

I am a beginner in Python and trying to find a solution for the following problem.

I have a csv file:

```
name, mark
Anna,24
John,19
Mike,22
Monica,20
Alex, 17
Daniel, 26

And xls file:

name, group
John, red
Anna, blue
Monica, blue
Mike, yellow
Alex, red
```

I am trying to get the result:

```
group, mark
Red, 26
Blue, 44
Yellow, 22
```

The number in result shows the total mark for the whole group.

I was trying to find similar problems but was not successful and I do not have much experience to find out what exactly I have to do and what commands to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with `df.merge` and `Groupby.sum`:

```
In [89]: df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

In [89]: df1
Out[89]: 
     name  mark
0    Anna    24
1    John    19
2    Mike    22
3  Monica    20
4    Alex    17
5  Daniel    26

In [90]: df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

In [90]: df2
Out[90]: 
     name   group
0    John     red
1    Anna    blue
2  Monica    blue
3    Mike  yellow
4    Alex     red

In [94]: df = df1.merge(df2).groupby('group').sum().reset_index()

In [95]: df
Out[95]: 
    group  mark
0    blue    44
1     red    36
2  yellow    22
```

**EDIT:** If you have other columns, which you don't want to `sum`, do this:

```
In [284]: df1.merge(df2).groupby('group').agg({'mark': 'sum'}).reset_index()
Out[284]: 
    group  mark
0    blue    44
1     red    36
2  yellow    22
```

Comment: Also, what if I have a third column in the first dataframe that also consist of numbers (age). How do I avoid summing up age as well without deleting the entire column?

Comment: @user14913431 Also, please check `EDIT` part in my updated answer.